# how to get number from Edittext in fragment class in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, toast

I have very strange problem with EditText!

I use EditText that user can enter his number and i want to get and show it on Toast/in another Activity. but  finally Toast shows nothing.this is my code. how can I solve it?

my java code:

```
 public class Step2Fragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText editText;
    public static String times;
    private Button start;

    public Step2Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step2, container, false);

        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.getNum);
        times= editText.getText().toString();

        start= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startCounting);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),times,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), CountActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("REPEATS",number);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

and my xml code:

```
<FrameLayout
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/texts"
    android:text="enter number please"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/getNum"
        android:inputType="number"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/startCounting"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>


  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> times= editText.getText().toString();

use this line inside `onClick` method.

```
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            times= editText.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),times,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), CountActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("REPEATS",number);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

You are assigning blank content to `times` because that time `EditText` is blank. You have to get the content when user click the button.

Comment: Welcome :) :) :)